# Kubernetes cannot pull image from public docker image repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am attempting to deploy a go application by following the documentation [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/deploy-go-application-kubernetes-helm/?fbclid=IwAR0zTAOCmzMk_NQ6wJuL04DNdku1BpjXq0MIz8W44KGPCf1YaENtAdIzlAk):

I have followed the steps in the documentation but am having an error with step 5. After installing running

```
Helm install RELEASE-NAME ./helm-chart/MYAPP
```

I attempt to run kubectl get pods, however none of the pods are ready.

After running

```
kubectl get pods
```

All of the listed pods have the status ImagePullBackOff.

I have tried to run kubectl describe pod , and have been given the following error:

```
Failed to pull image "mantissaa/todo-app": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for mantissaa/todo-app not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

I am unsure what other details need to be specified. Here is the docker hub repository for what I am attempting to deploy: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/mantissaa/todo-app/tags?page=1

Comment: If you don't have a tag it defaults to `latest`, which isn't listed on that tag page.  Do you mean `image: mantissaa/todo-app:0.1.0`?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: can you run `helm install RELEASE-NAME ./helm-chart/MYAPP --set image.tag=0.1.0`?

Answer (score 1):

Docker by default tries to use `latest` tag.
As per your private docker repository, you don't have it defined there. Instead, you have `0.1.0` tag only.

```
docker pull mantissaa/todo-app
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for mantissaa/todo-app:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown


docker pull mantissaa/todo-app:0.1.0
0.1.0: Pulling from mantissaa/todo-app
e7c96db7181b: Pull complete
a9b145f64bbe: Pull complete
3bcb5e14be53: Pull complete
1e6514cfa19a: Pull complete
fa28cb68c53c: Pull complete
064046777741: Pull complete
15442420c7af: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:b8327ea3eff41068eaa0d48c47687ef386e9f5de342758cca1f6735d53fc504a
Status: Downloaded newer image for mantissaa/todo-app:0.1.0
docker.io/mantissaa/todo-app:0.1.0
```

So you may want to update Image tag to `latest` or specify 0.1.0 tag in the `helm`